# Error with binary file

Tags: c, file, binary

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("F:\\hongphat.txt","wb+");
    char *password = "password";
    int l = strlen(password);
    fwrite(&l, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&password, 1, strlen(password), f);
    fclose(f);

    FILE *g = fopen("f:\\hongphat.txt", "rb+");
    char *passwordsame = new char[250];
    int length;
    fread(&length, sizeof(int), 1, g);
    fread(passwordsame, length, 1, g);
    int k = strlen(passwordsame);
    fclose(g);
    delete[]passwordsame;
}
```

i code this example to make a password for a file, but when i did that, i see that k is not equal to length ( length = 8), can anyone show my mistake

Answer (score 2):

When you write the password

```
fwrite(&password, 1, strlen(password), f);
```

The expression `&password` does not give you the password-string, it gives you the address of where the `password` *variable* is located. So what you are writing is the *pointer* to the string and not the string itself.

To solve it, just change to

```
fwrite(password, 1, strlen(password), f);
```

In other words, remove the address-of operator `&`.

---

You also have another mistake, in that when you read the password from the file, you don't *terminate* the string. All strings needs to be terminated by the character `'\0'`.

After you have read the length and the password, do e.g.

```
passwordsame[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: @PhátNguyễn You do the right thing with the length, there you need a pointer, but since `password` already is a pointer getting its address will give you a pointer to a pointer to `char` (or `char**`).

Comment: it seems have another mistake, k still not equal to length

Answer (score 0):

There is so many syntax error in this C code. In this code as you have used

> *password

for that you don't need to use '&' in the fwrite, but if you want to use '&' then you have to declare it

```
char password[]="password";
```

I modified your code a little. The code should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *f, *g;
    int l,k,length,n;
    char passwordsame[255];
    char password[]="password";
    f = fopen("hongphat.txt","wb+");
    l= strlen(password);
    fwrite(&l, sizeof(int), 1,f);
    fwrite(&password,strlen(password)+1,1, f);
    fclose(f);

    g = fopen("hongphat.txt", "rb+");
    fread(&length, sizeof(int), 1, g);
    printf("%d\n\n",length);
    fread(&passwordsame, length, 1, g);
    passwordsame[length]='\0';
    k = strlen(passwordsame);
    fclose(g);
}
```